# Standard width of checkbox and switch Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-checkbox

I cannot seem to find what the standard Checkbox width is. I would also like to know the width of a Switch too. I tried searching on Google and Stackoverflow, but I can only find problems of people willing to make a checkbox & switch bigger and smaller.

I would like to set the switch and checkbox to be the same width, but because they are both different in width, I wrapped a layout around it. I want to set a width to the layout, but I have to know what the width of both is in order to make it scale right for all devices.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some guides, the drawable of the Checkbox has a size of 20dp width and 20dp height.

The switch on the other hand is 40dp in width.

### **Answer:**

**Checkbox**

```
Width: 20dp
Height: 20dp
```

**Switch**

```
Width: 40dp
Height: unknown
```